# Accessing other users workspace

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

We are using TFS2012 with VS2008. We want to make changes, CheckIn in other users workspaces. Is there any way to access other users workspace through TFS like accessing local workspaces?

Answer (score 0):

You can only access someone else's workspace if you are on their machine, so long as the workspace is set as "Public".

If you need to change the access level of a workspace, get an administrator to use the `tf workspace` command and the `/permission` switch:

```
[/permission:(Private|PublicLimited|Public)]
```

You can get all the commands from `tf help workspace`.

TFS doesn't store the actual changes in the server workspace. Only if the files are latest version, what state (add/edit/delete/merge/etc.) they are in, any locks, and other meta-data is stored on the server.

Comment: So its entirely not possible to access workspaces in other machines??Thank you

Comment: No, you need access to their machine. You could use Remote Desktop to access it.